# Pre Installed Windows 8 on one hard drive and Ubuntu 12.10 on separate hard drive. Is this Possible?

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot

I recently purchased a HP Pavilion with Windows 8 pre installed.  I purchased a second hard drive and want to run Ubuntu 12.10.  Is it possible to boot from second hard drive and run Ubuntu without even touching Windows 8, or having to disconnect the first hard drive every time I want to run Ubuntu?  I'm new at this and could use help.  I have looked at many forums and all only discuss installing Ubuntu on the same hard drive as Windows 8.  I want to dual boot with two separate hard drives.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to update the bios to boot the ubuntu drive first, then grub will take over. I'm not sure if uefi will cause a complication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it is very common method to install Ubuntu. But dual booting Windows 8 with Ubuntu might be bit tricky.

This AU post should help you (even if it is for XP conceptually process is similar), [How do I install Ubuntu and Windows on separate hard drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162588/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-and-windows-on-separate-hard-drives).

Comment: Thank you for this.  It helped a lot.