# Installing Ubuntu on a laptop with preinstalled windows 8 (UEFI) with two hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have a Samsung laptop with a 128GB SSD (that has windows 8 preinstalled along with a recovery partition) and a 750GB HDD wich I use manly for files and programs.

I was wondering if I could partition the second hard drive (D:/) into two so I would have half of it for windows docs and programs and the other half to install ubuntu so I could dual boot.

I stumbled upon [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162588/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-and-windows-on-separate-hard-drives) wich mentions the process for windows XP and so I wanted to make sure I can do the same procedure for windows 8 (conisdering I have a UEFI motherboard)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a dual disk install but many many single ones and I can't see any reason why during the install when presented with the disk partitioning option that you wouldn't see the D: drive and be able to partition it ... BEST FIRST ... though to log into Windows and shrink the D:\ drive volume creating a spare space of 50% of the 750 and then use that to install Ubuntu on to ...
I would add an image but I don't have enough reputation ... soz ...

JUST AS an add on ...make sure you choose "Something Else" option on the "Allocate Drive Space" page .. as I can't add the image !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink the D drive from the below link.

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/11/shrink-resize-partitions-in-windows-8/

The shrink option provide's you the max extend to which you can shrink. If in case you aren't satisfied with the shrink space you need to relocate/backup some of the file's in the D-Drive.

Once this is done reboot into BIOS choose the boot/installation partition USB/CD drive.
If it is UEFI based then you need to opt for Legacy boot mode instead of UEFI in BIOS.

Now proceed with installation on to the newly created partition.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/

Regards,
Sajan